# kaggle cli installation error

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, kaggle

After installing kaggle, when I am passing kaggle command to command window it is throwing this error.

> Successfully installed kaggle-1.4.6 You are using pip version 10.0.1,
>   however version 18.0 is available. You should consider upgrading via
>   the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
>
> C:\Users\vkrnt>kaggle Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\users\vkrnt\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in
>   _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)   File "c:\users\vkrnt\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\vkrnt\Anaconda3\Scripts\kaggle.exe__main__.py", line 5, in
>      File
>   "c:\users\vkrnt\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kaggle__init__.py", line
>   23, in 
>       api.authenticate()   File "c:\users\vkrnt\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kaggle\api\kaggle_api_extended.py",
>   line 109, in authenticate
>       self._load_config(config_data)   File "c:\users\vkrnt\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kaggle\api\kaggle_api_extended.py",
>   line 151, in _load_config
>       raise ValueError('Error: Missing %s in configuration.' % item) ValueError: Error: Missing username in configuration.

Not able to find solution for this. Please help me out here.

Thanks.

Comment: I have added json file in .json folder as well.But still I am getting this error even when I am running any command.I went through kaggle_api_extended.py file and from first look it seems it has something to do with configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem although I used pipenv. To solve it I just followed the [API credentials](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api) section of kaggle-api readme. Extract from the readme:

> To use the Kaggle API, sign up for a Kaggle account at
>   https://www.kaggle.com. Then go to the 'Account' tab of your user
>   profile (https://www.kaggle.com//account) and select 'Create
>   API Token'. This will trigger the download of kaggle.json, a file
>   containing your API credentials. Place this file in the location
>   ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json (on Windows in the location C:\Users\.kaggle\kaggle.json - you can check the exact location, sans
>   drive, with echo %HOMEPATH%). You can define a shell environment
>   variable KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR to change this location to
>   $KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR/kaggle.json (on Windows it will be
>   %KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR%\kaggle.json